# Show logo/ad while content loads at the back end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to place a Logo/ad in front of content, there are ways to do it but the problem with them is that they use JS show/hide method. What happens is that the content doesn't load while user is watching the logo/ad, which results as double waiting for the user first for the logo/ad and then the actual flash content loading.
So I was thinking if there is a way that a logo/ad could be displayed and at the same time flash content continues to load at the back end. 
*I didn't ask for a loader that continues to appear until at the back end flash content is done loading, because I found only one script that was able to do so using Jquery but it was designed to work with fixed pixels while my flash content is based on %ages*

Live Demo: http://bloghutsbeta.blogspot.com/2012/04/testing-game-content-issue.html

Note: Sorry for providing blogspot link but JsFiddle is not an option for a person living in Afghanistan with 5KBps but still if you feel that I am missing something please let me know I will edit it and try my best to provide as relevant question as possible ^^

Relevant Markup:
Button for lightbox or Modal Window

```
<a class="poplight" href="#?w=100%" rel="popup_name"><img alt="play game" class="happybutton" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.8;this.filters.alpha.opacity=80" onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4084/4998558471_27e3985c16_m.jpg" style="opacity: 0.8;" /></a>
```

Content set to be display none until the above button is clicked

```
<div class="popup_block" id="popup_name">
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
        $('<iframe/>')
            .attr('frameborder', 0)
            .attr('allowTransparency', false)
            .attr('scrolling', 'no')
            .attr('width', '100%')
            .attr('height', '98%')
            .attr('src', 'http://files.cryoffalcon.com/bhgames/dressup/Celebrities/Wizard%20Fashion.html')
            .appendTo('#popup_name');
    });
});
</script>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fade { 
    display: none; 
    background: #000;
    position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    opacity: .80;
    z-index: 9999999;
}

.popup_block{
   width: 98.95%; height: 98.2%;
    display: none;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height:1em;
    font-size: 1em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px; left: 0px;
    z-index: 999999999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.close {
    height:20px;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;   
}
```

JS (actually Jquery)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

//When you click on a link with class of poplight and the href starts with a #
$('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

//Pull Query & Variables from href URL
var query= popURL.split('?');
var dim= query[1].split('&');
var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value

//Fade in the Popup and add close button
$('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('<a href="#" title="Close It" class="close"><img src="http://files.cryoffalcon.com/bloghuts/images/close%20button.png" alt="Close" width="20" height="20" /></a>');

//Define margin for center alignment (vertical + horizontal) - we add 80 to the height/width to accomodate for the padding + border width defined in the css
var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 0) / 0;
var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 0) / 0;

//Apply Margin to Popup
$('#' + popID).css({
'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
});

//Fade in Background
$('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
$('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer

return false;
});

//Close Popups and Fade Layer
$('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
$('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
$('#fade, a.close').remove();
}); //fade them both out

return false;
});

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try set events for flash content to notify that content has been downloaded ( this tutorial can help you http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/ ). While main contents does not receives signals from all content elements (if more than one) you can display modal window or just hide other content.